# How can I initialize an input field with the value of a URL query parameter?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vite

This is my Test code, I use Vite && Vue Router 4.x

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <label>測試</label><br>
            <input v-model="testInput" />
            <button @click="search">查詢</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ testInput }}
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script setup>
     import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
     import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router';
     const testInput = ref();
     const router = useRouter()
     const route = useRoute();
    
     console.log(route.query);
    
     
     onMounted(() => {
       testInput.value = route.query.testInput || '';
     });
    
     function search() {
        router.push({ name: 'Test', query: { testInput: testInput.value } });
     }
    
    </script>
```

Why doesn't the query value automatically populate in the router in my code?
This is my url

```
http://localhost/#/?testInput=aaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it can't find `name:'Test'`. If your route like this `http://localhost/#/Test?testInput=aaaa` is should work, or you can use it without route name

`router.push({ query: { testInput: testInput.value }, replace: true });`